# How to load "ionicons" font in expo sdk33?

Tags: react-native, expo

after upgrading to expo sdk 33.0.0, when i build my react native expo app everything is ok but as soon as the app starts the the following error shows up:

**fontFamily "ionicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync**

before the update i was using the sdk version 32.0.0 and everything was ok.

I tried to add the font as explained here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/ in my app.js componentDidMount function:

```
const Ionicons = require("./fonts/Ionicons.ttf");
...
componentDidMount() {
    ...
    Font.loadAsync({
        "Avenir-Book": AvenirBook,
        "Avenir-Light": AvenirLight,
        "Ionicons": Ionicons,
    })
}
...
```

I also try to change the name in the loadAsync from **"Ionicons"** to **"ionicons"** but nothing changed.

The **"Ionicons.ttf"** inside the fonts folder file was copied from the **node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts** folder

---------EDIT---------
In all my react native expo project src i have not a single reference to Ionicon

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: If you  use Ionicons, try this `import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';`

Comment: hi @hongdevelop, i tried your import but now i doesn't build and i get this error:  **asset.downloadAsync is not a function. (In 'asset.downloadAsync()', 'asset.downloadAsync' is undefined)**

Comment: `expo install asset => import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';`

Comment: The updated code is: 

`import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
...
componentDidMount() {
    ...
    Font.loadAsync({
        "Avenir-Book": AvenirBook,
        "Avenir-Light": AvenirLight,
        "Ionicons": Ionicons,
    })
}`
and the error is:  **asset.downloadAsync is not a function. (In 'asset.downloadAsync()', 'asset.downloadAsync' is undefined)**

But i'm not using Asset anywhere

Comment: You do not need to add 'ionics' to 'Font.loadAsync'.

Comment: ok but the error remains... as i wrote, before upgrading to sdk 33.0.0 everything was ok and i did not load Ionicons with Font.loadAsync. After the upgrade i got the error **fontFamily "ionicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync** so i tried to add it to Font.loadAsync but nothing changed

Comment: Same issue after upgrading to expo 35 from expo 34...

Answer (score 1):

To import `Ionicons` icons do

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
// use like
<Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />
```

And to import custom fonts, add the path to the font to require.

```
import { Font } from 'expo';

componentDidMount() {
  Font.loadAsync({
    'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Junius L.  the fact is that in my code there is no reference to "Ionicon" at all. For example i don't use tags like "<Ionicons .../>". So i thought that some component that i'm importing has the Ionicon dependency somehow but i can't load it... really strange issue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Container, Text } from 'native-base';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; // here, do a call "ionicons" font

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ionicons: Ionicons.font['ionicons'] // and here is what changes so that the font loads
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
      <Container>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok you can base yourself on the official documentation of native base and compare what changes from what I publish

Comment: try to use native-base@2.13.8 with  react-native-web@0.11.7. if you update these libraries it doesn't work for you, for now there is no viable solution for expo 36.

Answer (score 0):

## Nativebase

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }
```

## Me

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ionicons: Ionicons.font['ionicons'] // here
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }
```